# Send a keyboard shortcut to all of the panes for the current tmux session

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have some panes opened in `tmux` window. In all panes started performs some commands/programs. And I need to close all of them. Of course, I can manually switch to each pane and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. However, it is to long. Is there some way of some sort of *multicast* the shortcut to all of the `tmux` panes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a command in tmux, that lets send any commands/shortcuts to all of the panes:

<kbd>PREFIX</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`setw synchronize-panes`

<kbd>PREFIX</kbd> is a standard keyboard shortcut activates `tmux`. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in my tmux (other have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, for example)

Actually, I bind a couple of keyboard shortcuts in `~/.tmux-conf` to switch on/off panes synchronization:

```
bind e setw synchronize-panes on
bind E setw synchronize-panes off
```

Comment: Just to note, you don't need to set 2 keys, instead you can use one key to toggle synchronization option: `bind e set-window-option synchronize-panes`.

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me - instead had to do `bind e set -g synchronize-panes` as mentioned on https://fazlearefin.blogspot.com/2014/09/synchronize-panes-in-tmux-and-byobu.html

Comment: On Fedora, config file is 
`~/.tmux.conf`

and, as mentioned before, following binding works:
`bind e set -g synchronize-panes`